# Why does my phone's Bluetooth keep switching on automatically after every 5 minutes precisely? (Mi A2, Stock Android 10)

Tags: bluetooth, android-10, mi-a2

My Mi A2 recently started switching on its bluetooth automatically, and I set a stopwatch to count the minutes and it switches on after every 5 minutes dot on the clock. Please could ya help me out ASAP?

Answer (score 1):

Check if it stops in safe mode. If yes, some installed app is causing this. I uninstalled an app that I suspected was causing this and Bluetooth activation stopped

Comment: Please link the app